# Pinia state doesn't change on action

Tags: vue.js, action, vue-composition-api, pinia

I am using vue3 and for state managment i am using pinia.

Main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import './index.css'
import App from './App.vue'

import router from './router'
const pinia = createPinia()

createApp(App)
.use(pinia)
.use(router)
.mount('#app')
```

/store/index.js

```
 import { defineStore } from "pinia";

 export const useUserStore = defineStore("user", {
   state: () => ({
     data: {},
     token: null,
   }),
   actions: {
     setUser(userData) {
     alert(userData) // confirm that state really changes
     this.data = userData.data
     this.token = userData.token
     }
   },
 });
```

Vue template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ user }} {{ token }}
    <button @click="login">Login</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  import {useUserStore} from "@store";

  const store = useUserStore()
  const user = store.data
  const token = store.token

  const login = ()=> {
    const userData = {
      data: {
         name: 'Giorgi',
         lastname: 'Shalamberidze',
         email: 'gigi@gmail.com'
      },
      token: 'MY_API_TOKEN'
    }
    store.setUser(userData)
 }
 </script>
```

so as you can see i have alert function in setUser state to check if action working when clicking on logn button in template. but it not working in template for example when click on login this action run and state changes but they dont displaying in Vue template. but when i changee something in vue template and than save with ctrl + s its displaying. i dont know what i am doing wrong please help me thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to destructure your store with `storeToRefs` which will maintain the reactivity of the state, meaning your UI will rerender on state change.

```js
import { storeToRefs } from "pinia";

const store = useUserStore();
const { data: user, token } = storeToRefs(store); // destructures "data" from store to new variable "user"
```

[Documentation reference](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#Destructuring-from-a-Store)

Answer (score 0):

Use ref explicitly can help Vue's reactivity system work more predictably. Modify your store like this:

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { ref } from "vue";

export const useUserStore = defineStore("user", {
  state: () => ({
    data: ref({}),
    token: ref(null),
  }),
  actions: {
    setUser(userData) {
      this.data = userData.data;
      this.token = userData.token;
    },
  },
});
```

Wrap template variables in a computed property. This ensures that the template always reads the reactive data. Change your Vue template script section like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ user }} {{ token }}
    <button @click="login">Login</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { useUserStore } from "@store";
  import { computed } from "vue";

  const store = useUserStore();
  const user = computed(() => store.data);
  const token = computed(() => store.token);

  const login = () => {
    const userData = {
      data: {
        name: 'Giorgi',
        lastname: 'Shalamberidze',
        email: 'gigi@gmail.com'
      },
      token: 'MY_API_TOKEN'
    };
    store.setUser(userData);
  };
</script>
```